# Convert ami creation date from string to datetime format

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

How to convert ami creation date from string to datetime format? I am using boto3, i need to convert ami.creation_date from sting format to datetime.

Comment: At least include an example of the string format in your question. This isn't going to be an AWS specific answer, it's just a Python string to date question. If you included the example date string in your question anybody that knows Python, not just AWS experts, would be able to give you the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
t = datetime.datetime.strptime(i.image.creation_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

The string for `image.creation_date` looks like `"2017-08-11T09:31:59.000Z"`

To get the time in seconds since 1970: `secs = t.timestamp()`